# Подмена контента в зависимости от адреса сайта

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс

Есть три url. Сайт по сути один, но разбит на поддомены (региональные, например, spb.site.ru ), информация дублируется на всех.
Возникла необходимость сделать следующее, на странице обратной связи указать контакты (почта, телефон и т.д для региона взятого), но  информация вбивается единожды и на всех трёх одинаковая, как подменять информацию (почта, телефон) для каждого адреса? Подскажите, пожалуйста

P.s: cms битрикс

Answer (score 0):

```
if (url1) {echo"<div>nomer</div>"}
```

Вы не уточняли, что и как дайте больше подробностей, чтобы я вам помог

Comment: Есть три url, чтобы страница «контакты» для каждого url отображала свои данные (почту, номера). Например, человек зашёл на 1.site.ru и там один номер телефона и почта, а потом перешёл на эту же страницу но с другого домена 2.site.ru и там контакты изменились на другие

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "spb.site.ru"){
    $phone = "+711111111";
    $mail = "spb@mail.ru";
} else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "msk.site.ru"){
    $phone = "+722222222";
    $mail = "msk@mail.ru";
} else {
    $phone = "+733333333";
    $mail = "vrn@mail.ru";
}

echo $phone;
echo $mail;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]